# Determining when QuickTime stops recording using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm using the following AppleScript to determine when the user clicks the stop recording button in the task bar:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    tell document 1
        activate
        new screen recording
        delay 1
        tell application "System Events" to key code 49
        delay 2
        repeat until (new screen recording) is false
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Though instead the script keeps relaunching QuickTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the result of the `new screen recording` command into a variable.

Use the **exists** command to check this document

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set tdoc to new screen recording --> document "Screen Recording"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events" to key code 49
    delay 2
    repeat while exists tdoc
        delay 1
    end repeat
    -- the recording is stopped
    tell front document
        -- do something with the front document ("Untitled")
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Is there a way to wait until QuickTime exports the movie? Also the Dictionary, online tutorials, and other StackOverflows have incorrect scripts. Where do I find information on writing AppleScripts?